# When is obj.GetType().IsInstanceOfType(typeof(MyClass)) true?

Tags: c#, types, isinstance

I'm looking at this piece of code written by someone else, and I'm wondering when it would evaluate to true.  Basically, it is saying someType is an instance of someOtherType.  Does it even make sense?  So far, I've tried:

```
derivedClass.GetType().IsInstanceOfType(typeof(BaseClass)) 

baseClass.GetType().IsInstanceOfType(typeof(DerivedClass)) 

myClass.GetType().IsInstanceOfType(typeof(MyClass))
```

And all of them evaluate to false.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: you might want to refactor and use the `is` operator.

Comment: `typeof` returns an object `System.Type`, that's why it's always false. Changing it to `derivedClass is BaseClass` is much better.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Each of those 3 lines will return true **only** if the object involved (`derivedClass`, `baseClass` and `myClass` respectively) is an instance of `object`, or of the undocumented `RuntimeType` object (note that [Type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/42892f65) is abstract), so for example the following would result in true statements:

```
var myObject = new object();
myObject.GetType().IsInstanceOfType(typeof(Console));

myObject = typeof(Object);
myObject.GetType().IsInstanceOfType(typeof(Console));
```

Note that the type used (in this case `Console`) doesn't matter and has no effect on the outcome of the statement.

**Why?**

The documentation for [IsInstanceOfType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.isinstanceoftype.aspx) tells us that it will return true if the object passed in is an instance of current type, so for example the following statement will return true if `myForm` is a class that derives from `Form`, otherwise it will return false.

```
typeof(Form).IsInstanceOfType(myForm);
```

In your case `myForm` is in fact `typeof(BaseClass)`, which is of the undocumented type `RuntimeType` (which derives from `Type`), and so you are only going to get `true` returned if this undocumented type happens to derive from the provided type - this is unlikely to be the desired behaviour.

**What should I use instead?**

What you are probably after is the [is keword](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/scekt9xw%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), which returs true if the provided object is an instance of the given type

```
derivedClass is BaseClass
baseClass is DerivedClass
myClass is MyClass
```

Comment: I believe you're confusing IsAssignableFrom and IsInstanceOfType. Your code is asking "Is this object of type Type an instance of type Type?" which will always be true. The 'is' keyword can't always be used, as you sometimes have an object of Type.

Answer (score 8):

`IsInstanceOfType()` checks whether the *instance* that you pass it is an instance of the type you called it on.

You're passing a `System.Type` instance to `IsInstanceOfType()`.  That will only be true if you call it on `typeof(Type)` or one of its base classes.

Comment: Do you mean `myClass.GetType().IsInstanceOfType(typeof(Type))`?

Comment: @user1486691: No.  `typeof(Type).IsInstanceOfType(anyType)` will return true for any `Type `instance.  `IsInstanceOfType` is not supposed to take a type.

Comment: typeof(DateTime).IsInstanceOfType(new DateTime()): true

Answer (score 3):

The [`Type.IsInstanceOf` documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.isinstanceoftype.aspx) says that `Type.IsInstanceOfType(o)` return "**true** if the current **Type** is in the inheritance hierarchy of the object represented by **o**, or if the current **Type** is an interface that **o** supports."

In the above examples, the `Type` is the type returned by `GetType()`, so it is the type of the object at the far left. The object `o` is `typeof(BaseClass)`, which is of type `Type`. The current `Type` is `DerivedClass` and the object `o` is `typeof(BaseClass)`. The type of `o` is `Type`.

Plug that into the documentation. It returns "**true** if `DerivedClass` is in the inheritance hierarchy of `Type`."

This is rarely true.

The author almost certainly intended `typeof(BaseClass).IsInstanceOfType(derivedClass)`, which is much more easily written as `derivedClass is BaseClass`.

Answer (score 0):

It is true when the object you call GetType() on is an instance of the System.Type object passed as an argument to the parameter of the IsInstanceOfType() method.

Answer (score 0):

`IsInstanceOfType` Determines whether the specified object is an instance of the current Type.

Sample : IsInstanceOfType(o)

true if the current Type is in the inheritance hierarchy of the object represented by o, or if the current Type is an interface supported by o. false if none of these conditions is not met, or if o is null, or if the current Type is an open generic type