# C#: Check whether an object is derived from class described by a Type object

Tags: c#, inheritance, reflection, types

I have a `Type` `T`, which I've loaded from an assembly via `assembly.GetType("namespace.TypeName")`, and an `object` `o` of an unknown class, received from a different place.

I need to check whether `o` is derived from `T`.

I've tried:

- `T.IsInstanceOfType(o)`, which does not work as expected, as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12160460/when-is-obj-gettype-isinstanceoftypetypeofmyclass-true)
- `o is T`, which yields the compiler error `'T' is a 'field' but a 'type' was expected`

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at the [IsAssignableFrom Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.isassignablefrom%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
Type t = ...
Object o = ...

bool isODerivedFromT = (o == null) || t.IsAssignableFrom(o.GetType());
```