# how to correctly evaluate .GetType().IsInstanceOfType(typeof(Interface<>))

Tags: c#

How can I make code below return `true`?

> 1. *`handler` variable defined as an `object` on purpose to mimic the actual environment.*
> 2. *I already read [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12160460/when-is-obj-gettype-isinstanceoftypetypeofmyclass-true](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12160460/when-is-obj-gettype-isinstanceoftypetypeofmyclass-true_)*

```
void Main()
{
    object handler = new TestIntegrationEventHandler();
    Type eventType = typeof(TestIntegrationEvent);
    Type concreteType = typeof(IIntegrationEventHandler<>).MakeGenericType(eventType);
    Console.WriteLine(handler.GetType().IsInstanceOfType(concreteType));
}

public class TestIntegrationEvent : IntegrationEvent
{
}

public class IntegrationEvent
{
}

public class TestIntegrationEventHandler : IIntegrationEventHandler<TestIntegrationEvent>
{
    public async Task Handle(TestIntegrationEvent @event)
    {
    }
}

public interface IIntegrationEventHandler<in TIntegrationEvent> : IIntegrationEventHandler where TIntegrationEvent : IntegrationEvent
{
    Task Handle(TIntegrationEvent @event);
}

public interface IIntegrationEventHandler
{
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is the other way round!

```
private static void Main()
{
    object handler = new TestIntegrationEventHandler();
    Type eventType = typeof(TestIntegrationEvent);
    Type concreteType = typeof(IIntegrationEventHandler<>).MakeGenericType(eventType);
    Console.WriteLine(concreteType.IsInstanceOfType(handler));
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

From the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type.isinstanceoftype?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev15.query%3FappId%3DDev15IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.Type.IsInstanceOfType);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.7);k(DevLang-csharp)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=netframework-4.7.2) for `IsInstanceOfType`:

> Determines whether the specified object is an instance of the current Type.

So, you are asking whether `IIntegrationEventHandler<TestIntegrationEvent>` is an instance of type `TestIntegrationEventHandler`, which is false of course. Although I really think that the method's name does not help much...